# What's the expression of $\frac{\delta F}{\delta P_i}$

Tags: partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

$$F=\int|\nabla \vec P|^2dv$$ $$\vec P=(P_x,P_y)$$
what's the expression of $\frac{\delta F}{\delta P_i}$,($i=x,y)$